I want to create Interactive report for failure records for data Loading Page
I have Multiple data Loading Page, To be Precised 10. I want to create Interactive report for failure records for data Loading Page

So ... what have you tried and what errors did you get ?

First thing is I wanted to know if its possible. As I'm using data Loading page for first time

Well... you'll have to do your research.  2 minutes of googling let me to this blog - so yes there is a possibility to use an error table. If there is a table, then you can create an interactive report on it.
I've worked with data loading in previous projects but I don't remember the details
